# Colorbox resize on form validation (jQuery validate)

Tags: ajax, jquery-validate, colorbox

Okay so here's the deal :

I call the form in Colorbox through AJAX, and have set up a callback to handle its validation, which works fine. Only problem is, when I try to resize the box when fields are invalid (which generates a label with a class of error), in only works on the second try.

I call the resize method on a click event, and it works only at the second click.

I suspect this is because it tries to resize before the labels are generated...I don't know how to circumvent that issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(".colorbox").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var el = $(this),
        sdHref = (el.attr("data-sd-href") ? el.attr("data-sd-href") : el.attr("href")),
        sdTitle = (el.attr("data-sd-title") ? el.attr("data-sd-title") : el.attr("title")),
        sdIframe = (el.attr("data-sd-iframe") ? true : false),
        sdWidth = (el.attr("data-sd-width") ? el.attr("data-sd-width") : false),
        sdHeight = (el.attr("data-sd-height") ? el.attr("data-sd-height") : false);

    $.colorbox({
        href: sdHref,
        title: sdTitle,
        iframe: sdIframe,
        width: sdWidth,
        height: sdHeight,
        scrolling: false,
        onComplete: function() { // I validate the form once the content is loaded
            $("form").validate({
                rules: {
                    phone: {
                        minlength: 10,
                        maxlength:10,
                        digits: true                    
                    }
                }
            });         
        }
    });
});

$('body').click(function(event) { // Even bubbling works on clicking the button, but only on the second try...
   if ($(event.target).is('button[type=submit]')) {
     $.colorbox.resize();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

my solution:

```
 $('#form_nuevo_almacen').validate({           
    rules: {
        nombre: {
            required: true,
        },
        clave: {
            required: true,
        }

    },
    messages: {
        nombre: {
            required: "Almacen requerido",
        },
        clave:{
            required:'Clave requerida',
        }
    },
     showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        this.defaultShowErrors();
        $.colorbox.resize();
    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        form.submit();
        $.colorbox.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :

```
$(".colorbox").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this),
        sdHref = (el.attr("data-sd-href") ? el.attr("data-sd-href") : el.attr("href")),
        sdTitle = (el.attr("data-sd-title") ? el.attr("data-sd-title") : el.attr("title")),
        sdIframe = (el.attr("data-sd-iframe") ? true : false),
        sdWidth = (el.attr("data-sd-width") ? el.attr("data-sd-width") : false),
        sdHeight = (el.attr("data-sd-height") ? el.attr("data-sd-height") : false);

    $.colorbox({
        href: sdHref,
        title: sdTitle,
        iframe: sdIframe,
        width: sdWidth,
        height: sdHeight,
        scrolling: false,
        onComplete: function() { // I validate the form once the content is loaded
            $("form").validate({
                rules: {
                    phone: {
                        minlength: 10,
                        maxlength:10,
                        digits: true                    
                    }
                },
                invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                    if (errors) {
                        window.setTimeout('$.colorbox.resize()',10);
                    }
                }
            });         
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am trying to duplicate/modify your answer for my very same problem. Tho I am using an inline form. Any help on modifying your solution to work with my form would be a great help.

<div id="colorboxwrapper">
    <form action="login.php" method="post" name="logForm" id="logForm">
    <input name="doLogin" type="submit" id="doLogin3" class="button" value="Login">
    </form>
</div>